# How to truncate very long tick labels on y-axis of subplots and fit plot and labels neatly in one fig using matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Below is my code. I would like to truncate the y-axis tick labels. I can't truncate the field that is being used for the labels because then the data will aggregate improperly. I need to truncate the strings being used for the label. Let's say the first 100 characters per string. How would I truncate for each subplot in this manner to be able to neatly show all the labels and subplots in one figure?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, sharex = True, figsize=(15,10))

a = q3[:10].plot(kind='barh',stacked=True,colormap='Reds',rot=0, legend = None,  ax = ax[0,0])
b = q1[:10].plot(kind='barh',stacked=True,colormap='Reds',rot=0, legend = None,ax = ax[0,1])
c = q4[:10].plot(kind='barh',stacked=True,colormap='Reds',rot=0, legend = None,ax = ax[1,0])
d = q2[:10].plot(kind='barh',stacked=True,colormap='Reds',rot=0, legend = None,ax = ax[1,1])


plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't truncate the field that is being used for the labels because then the data will aggregate improperly.

By default, pandas uses the index to set the tick labels. However, you can create another column of truncated labels and then tell pandas to use that for setting the y-tick labels.

```
q3.plot(kind='barh', ..., yticks=q3['my_column_with_truncated_strings'])
```

Alternatively, you can use matplotlib directly:

```
axes[0,0].set_yticklabels(q3['my_column_with_truncated_strings'])
```